"Different than" followed by nominative case?
I'm going to try to explain my question as clearly as I can:
"Different" usually takes a preposition, either "from" (standard English regardless of region), "to" (British English), or "than" (American English.) But "than" differs from the other options because, unlike conventional prepositions, it can also be used as a conjunction and take the nominative case: grammatically conservative dialects and styles of English prefer "He is taller than I." Even though "different" normally takes a preposition followed by objective case, do any English speakers (or usage authorities?) also consider a sentence like "My parents look different than I" acceptable?

The existing questions have some information: this and this. The former quotes AUE: "Different than" is sometimes used to avoid the cumbersome "different from that which", etc. (e.g., "a very different Pamela
than I used to leave all company and pleasure for" -- Samuel
Richardson).

And this is the canonical post on "than him" vs "than he".

The usage  for different  differs from that for comparatives.

My late aunt was an English teacher in the UK and she would be spinning in her grave if she heard me use anything other than "different from". As far as she was concerned that is the only grammatically correct construct,

@PeterJennings As stated in the question, "different than" is primarily an American construction.

I think this is a strong argument for using 'different from' and the objective case.
